# Google Sheets Auto Repeat Using arrayformula()

Tags: google-sheets

Based on this [sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EkQNz0ar93fgKsEdnih7FiaVZrY3XbTFOOWQ_jMnUlg/edit?usp=sharing), I have this formula which gives me the accurate results with one major problem... It does not auto-populate to new rows

`=arrayformula(if(countif(filter(G$2:G,A$2:A=A2,B$2:B=B2),">"&G2)>0,countif(filter(G$2:G,A$2:A=A2,B$2:B=B2),">"&G2),COUNTIF(filter(E$2:E,A$2:A=A2,B$2:B=B2),"Finished")))`

I have tried this formula to see if it will auto-populate to the new rows...

`=arrayformula(IF(ISNA(A2:A),,if(countif(filter(G$2:G,A$2:A=A2,B$2:B=B2),">"&G2)>0,countif(filter(G$2:G,A$2:A=A2,B$2:B=B2),">"&G2),COUNTIF(filter(E$2:E,A$2:A=A2,B$2:B=B2),"Finished"))))`

...the above formula does auto-populate; however, every value is `1` instead of the correct value.

I tried a simple formula which does not do everything the above does but might help troubleshoot. I was under the suspicion that the above formula was only displaying results of the first row over and over. To test I tried this formula...

`=arrayformula(IF(ISNA(A2:A),,indirect("g"&ROW(indirect("g2:g"&counta(G2:G))))))`

...it turns out that the above formula does display the results from G2 into each row. If I could figure out the reason why, I am sure I could take the concept from the solution to this simple formula and add it to the above more complex one.

Comment: can you share a sample sheet - I have an idea where there might possibly be the issue - but without any idea or sample dummy data to test it on its impossible to guess at what your trying to do

Comment: @AuriellePerlmann - Column "I" does auto-populate to new rows but produces the incorrect values. Column "J" produces the correct values; however, the formula was manually copied to each row.

Comment: @AuriellePerlmann - The link I provided earlier did not allow you adequate permissions... This one should do the trick... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EkQNz0ar93fgKsEdnih7FiaVZrY3XbTFOOWQ_jMnUlg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: trying a couple different things, its only the last function that is preventing the array formula

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why your comparing the countif to column G, this is a timestamp in your sheet.

Comment: @AuriellePerlmann Yes... I am checking to see if there are later entries that match both column A and column B. The exception to that rule is if it is marked as "Finished" in column E. I have other functions that only pull values marked as 0. If it is 0 then I know it is the latest entry matching column A and B. If it is marked as "Finished, it also will not be 0"

Comment: If there is a better way to do it... I'm not sure how. Basically what I need is the value to only be 0 if there are no entries with a later timestamp that match column A and B. Also if it is the latest entry and column E equals "Finished", it should not be 0.

Comment: I'll take a look again but I'll have to do it after work so it won't be till this evening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(
 mmult(
  --(A2:A=TRANSPOSE(A2:A))*
  --(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(B2:B))*
  --(G2:G<TRANSPOSE(G2:G)),
  row(A2:A)^0)>0,
 mmult(
  --(A2:A=TRANSPOSE(A2:A))*
  --(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(B2:B))*
  --(G2:G<TRANSPOSE(G2:G)),
  row(A2:A)^0),
 mmult(
  --(A2:A=TRANSPOSE(A2:A))*
  --(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(B2:B)),
  --(E2:E="Finished"))
 )
)
```

*Caution!* It works slow, so it's better to delete blank rows in  the worksheet. Even better to use this formula in 2 steps. Step 1 formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(--(A2:A=TRANSPOSE(A2:A))*
--(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(B2:B))*
--(G2:G<TRANSPOSE(G2:G)),
row(A2:A)^0))
```

And step 2 formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(--(A2:A=TRANSPOSE(A2:A))
*--(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(B2:B)),
--(E2:E="Finished")))
```

Open ranges overload this formula. It also could work faster if you use:

- `offset(E2,,,counta(E2:E))` instead of `E2:E`